# Leaving group stability when treated with grignard

Tags: grignard-reagent

Why does $\ce{-NH2}$ not leave in $\ce{RCONH2}$ while in $\ce{RCONR2}$ $\ce{NR2}$ leaves when treated with Grignard?
I thought $\ce{NH2}$ should leave as there negative charge is more stable on $\ce{N}$ compared to $\ce{NR2}$ where the alkyl groups have a +I effect already.

Comment: I would appreciate answers instead of downvotes :)

Comment: Well, that's pretty obvious, you just don't use grigniards with compounds having even weakly acidic hydrogens.

Comment: Ikr but suppose if I use 2 eqt of grignard then why wouldnt NH2 leave ? Why does only NR2 leaves?

Comment: Grignard reagents with deprotonate amides and the RN- species is not a leaving group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{RCONH_2}$ is a protic acid, and even though it's weak the Grignard reagent is a powerful enough proton base to react.  You get deprotonation of the amide instead of nucleophilic attack on the carbonyl group.